# Understanding the recursive knapsack

Tags: c++, recursion, knapsack-problem

When I learned recursion, I understood it with 3 steps, where one of them was the assumption step. For example, if I want to find the sum of n integers:

```
int func(int n)
{
  if(n <= 1)
     return n;
  int ans = func(n-1); //Assumption step
  return ans + n;
}
```

When `n = 5`, then In the assumption step I assume that `func(n-1)` ie; `func(4)` will give me the correct answer 10. So keeping that assumption in mind, I just write `return ans + n;` Since I know `ans` has 10 in it and then just add the current `n` to it, which will give me my answer of 15.

 Now when I look at the knapsack code:

```
int knapsack(int wt[], int val[], int capacity, int n)
{
     if (n == 0 || capacity == 0)
           return 0;
     
     if(wt[n-1] > capacity)
           return knapsack(wt, val, capacity-wt[n-1], n-1);
     
     return max(val[n-1] + knapsack(wt, val, capacity-wt[n-1], n-1), knapsack(wt, val, capacity, n-1));
    
}
int main()
{
  int wt[] = {1, 3, 4, 5};
  int val[] = {1, 4, 5, 7};
  int capacity = 7;
  cout<<knapsack(wt,val,capacity, 4); // gives 9
}
```

Which function do I trust to give me the solution for the smaller value  `n-1` and what will it be. How can I apply and understand the assumption step in the knapsack code?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by an assumption step?

Comment: It's the step where I trust that when the function is called with a smaller value/input, it will then give me the correct answer. Then I use that smaller correct answer to construct my overall final return statement. Just like in the sum of n integers example above.

Comment: Each time that funciton is called, n is decremented, if n was initially positive then one or many of the recursions will eventually be zero (terminating the recursion).

Comment: The code, as written, doesn't compile. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: When the ```wt[] = {1, 3, 4, 5}``` and ```val[] = {1, 4, 5, 7}``` and the ```capacity = 7``` is passed into the knapsack function, we will get an output of  9. Since taking the objects of weights 4, 3 will be optimal to give a weight of 9.

Comment: I feel it's already a minimal reproducible example. We just need to pass the weight, val, capacity, size of array details to the function with a call from the main() function.

Comment: I have added the main() function now and fixed a typo in the knapsack code. It will compile fine now.